# Radioactivity and Rules- difference between "add an incident" and "set the energy"

Tags: rules

I want to increase the radioactivity level after flagging the node.
But I don't know exactly how to set the value.

If I fill in the value form field with 60, the Radioactivity text field will increase over 200.

So maybe the action settings are wrong. 
**What is the difference between the following actions?**

- *add an incident to a field*
- *set the energy of a field*

Answer (score 1):

You can do any custom logic you want using the Rules module which integrates with the radioactivity module.

Add an incident to a field - this **increments or decrements** the energy level by a specified amount.
Set the energy of a field - this **sets** the energy level to the specified amount.

Comment: Thank you Thomas,
but when i "set" the energy level it will also increase? Maybe my condition settings are wrong.